# how to spilit list into sublists in C# without using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, arraylist

I have a string list which I do not know its size at first.I want divide it into groups with length of 100 without using LINQ.

```
if (result["PASSED"].Count > 0){
// divide it into groups with length of 100 and then for each group do
// the following method.
    handler.send ( result["PASSED"].ToArray (), smscontext );
}
```

Comment: Why do you _not_ want to use LINQ?

Comment: I forced to not using it.

Comment: That's too bad. These problems are why LINQ exists.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: For example because you can only use .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public static List<List<string>> ListToSublists(List<string> lsSource)
        {
            List<List<string>> lsTarget = new List<List<string>>();

            List<string> ls = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < lsSource.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (i % 100 == 0)
                {
                    if(ls != null)
                        lsTarget.Add(ls);
                    ls = new List<string>();
                }
                ls.Add(lsSource[i]);
            }

            if(ls != null)
                lsTarget.Add(ls);
            return lsTarget;
        }




    public static void main()
    {
        var yourlist = new List<string>();
        yourlist.AddRange( /* Whatever */ ); 
        List<List<string>> ls = ListToSublists(yourlist );

        foreach (List<string> result in ls)
        {

            if (result.Count > 0)
            {
                handler.send(result.ToArray(), smscontext);
            }

        }
    }
```